# Dictionary.ContainsKey() not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<YMD, object> cache = new Dictionary<YMD, object>();
```

The YMD class is one of my inventions, it is a class containing only the year, month, and date. The purpose is that the data will be indexed by the day is relates to. Anyhow, I have implemented the Equals() and CompareTo() functions, as well as the == and != operators.

Despite this, the Dictionary.ContainsKey() function will always return false, even if the key exists.

I immediately thought my comparison functions must be broken, but after writing unit tests for all of them it does not appear to be the case.

Is there something about the dictionary class that I do not know?

Comment: Its a class. Pretty sure the Dictionary is not comparing the class reference because the == operator has been overridden.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a dictionary, `GetHashCode()` is critical. For things that are equal (`Equals() == true`) it **must** return the same number (but it is permitted to have collisions - i.e. two items can return the same number by coincidence but not be considered equals).

Additionally - the hash-code must **not** change while the item is in the dictionary. Hashing on `readonly` values are good for this, but alternatively: just don't change it! For example, if your equals / hashcode spans an entities `Name` and `Id` (say), then don't change those properties of the object, or you may never see that record again (even if you pass in the same instance as the key).

Comment: The object is immutable, so the hash will not change. Thank you for your answer, spot on :)

Answer (score 2):

You need only to override the **Equals** and **GetHashcode** functions.
The most common implementation for GetHashcode is to XOR (^) all of the instance's data members.