# How can Contains returns false but GetHashCode() returns the same number, and Equals returns true?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, equals, contains, gethashcode

I have an entity class like this (with lots of stuff missing):

```
class Parent
{
    private readonly Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Child> children =
        new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Child>();

    public virtual void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        if (!this.children.Contains(child))
        {
            this.children.Add(child);
            child.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public virtual void RemoveChild(Child child)
    {
        if (this.children.Contains(child))
        {
            child.Parent = null;
            this.children.Remove(child);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to remove a child, the `if` statement evaluates to `false`.  So, I put a breakpoint on the `if` statement, and evaluated certain expressions:

```
this.children.Contains(child) => false
this.children.ToList()[0].Equals(child) => true
this.children.ToList()[0].GetHashCode() => 1095838920
child.GetHashCode() => 1095838920
```

My understanding is that if `GetHashCode` returns identical values, it then checks `Equals`.  Why is `Contains` returning false?

---

Both of my `Parent` and `Child` entities inherit from a common `Entity` base class, which is a non-generic version of the generic entity base class from page 25 of the NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook.  Here is my base class:

```
public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Entity);
    }

    private static bool isTransient(Entity obj)
    {
        return obj != null &&
            Equals(obj.Id, Guid.Empty);
    }

    private Type getUnproxiedType()
    {
        return GetType();
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(Entity other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        if (!isTransient(this) &&
            !isTransient(other) &&
            Equals(Id, other.Id))
        {
            var otherType = other.getUnproxiedType();
            var thisType = getUnproxiedType();
            return thisType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType) ||
                otherType.IsAssignableFrom(thisType);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (Equals(Id, Guid.Empty))
            return base.GetHashCode();

        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

---

After further investigation, I feel something like this is happening:

1. Calling `parent.AddChild(child)`
2. Saving to the database, which caused `child.Id` to be generated
3. Calling `parent.RemoveChild(child)`

...and as discussed below, this was changing `GetHashCode()`.

This was the result of a bug in my program - I was supposed to reload `parent` between steps 2 and 3.

Still, I think there's something more fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you test it with `private Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Child> children = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Child>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this to work, I had to change my `Entity` class' `GetHashCode` method to lazy-evaluate the hash code, but once computed, cache the result and never let it change.  Here is my new implementation of `GetHashCode`:

```
    private int? requestedHashCode;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (!requestedHashCode.HasValue)
        {
            requestedHashCode = isTransient(this) 
                ? base.GetHashCode() 
                : this.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
        return requestedHashCode.Value;
    }
```

For a better implementation of a base entity class, see [AbstractEntity](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns.Entities/AbstractEntity.cs).

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any other way that this could happen - `Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet` must contain its own `Contains` that behaves differently than we expect.

Comment: Looking into it with ReSharper, it's just a wrapper around a standard `Dictionary<T,object>` and `Contains` calls `ContainsKey`.

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197678/dictionary-containskey-not-working-as-expected) about Dictionary.ContainsKey

Answer (score 3):

Does `Child` both override `object.Equals(object)` and implement `IEquatable<Child>`? It's possible that the equality that the collection is doing isn't the same as the `Equals` method you're calling on the 2nd line of your code sample.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen if `Equals(Child)` is implemented differently to the override of `Equals(object)`. It would really depend on what `Child` looked like.

It can *also* happen due to the effect that Henk mention - is `Parent` part of the calculation of the hash code and equality, for example? If so, setting `Parent` to `null` will probably change the hash code of the child to be one other than the hash code which is recorded in the `HashSet`. It's not a problem if `Parent` *isn't* part of the equality/hash calculation, although it's still somewhat odd to put a mutable type into a hash set or use it as the key in a hash table.

Comment: Good points.  Both derive from a common `Entity` base class (recommended from all NHibernate literature).  I've posted the base class above.