# Unique keys in Dictionary for class containing longs

Tags: c#

If I want to use objects of this class as keys in a Dictionary, what do I need to do? (10.0, 20.0) shouldn't exist as a key twice.

```
public class IntPoint
{
    public Int64 X { get; set; }
    public Int64 Y { get; set; }

    public IntPoint(Int64 X, Int64 Y)
    {
        this.X = X; this.Y = Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public static Dictionary<IntPoint, List<int>> GetPolygonDuplicateIndixes(Polygon p)
{
    Dictionary<IntPoint, List<int>> d = new Dictionary<IntPoint, List<int>>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach(IntPoint point in p)
    {
        if(!d.ContainsKey(point))
        {
            d[point] = new List<int>();
        }
        d[point].Add(i);
        i++;
    }
    ...
```

I'm getting duplicates in d. Why? 22002, 1501 occurs twice in p.

Comment: Even if this is not your current issue: [beware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197678/dictionary-containskey-not-working-as-expected) of using mutable fields for hashing a key for Dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [Dictionary documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90.aspx), you'll see that if the keys implement
[IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), that equality implementation will be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your GetHashCode can look like:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode();
}
```

But you still need to override `Equals` and implement `IEquatable` interface.

You may also use `Tuple<Int64, Int64>` instead of your own `IntPoint` class (if you're on .NET 4.0).

Comment: +1 for recommending Tuple. That seems like a better approach, especially with IStructuralEquatable for compares.

Answer (score 2):

The following link from MSDN recommends using combining X and Y using an XOR operation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx#Y1500

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
  return X ^ Y;
```

}

The thing to remember is that

1. It is important that the hash computation is fast
2. If two objects are equal then there hash mush be equal, but two objects with the same hash *do not necessarily* have to be equal